# Android: Regular UI Updates & Communication Service <-> Activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity, updates

So what I'm trying to do is just updating an activity's views in intervals like, say, once per second. In this specific case a handful of buttons, and all I want to change is their text. I've read quite a few questions here addressing the same problem, but I seem to be stuck a little more than other people, and I'm going to blame that on my restricted experience with Android (which actually means, I did not understand the solutions proposed, or was unable to identify the core ideas in the sample code, and that this is actually the first time I'm trying to program for Android).

Since I would like a service to own the data (and its creation), I thought of a callback to the activity, and that's what I've been trying got get my head around for the past few hours. What I do have is a service with `onCreate()`, `onStartCommand()` and `onDestroy()` and basically, that's fine. I registered it in the android manifest file, and succeeded at bringing it to life (I'm logging the lifecycle methods).

But how do I get to

- have the Views updated frequently with the data from the service
- give the service certain information it depends on (like notifying it of a button event)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here is a complete and current example http://blog.philippheckel.com/2012/06/10/android-example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging/

Comment: I've read into it and it seems like someone encapsulated the actual work to be done - that's a nice thing to offer to anyone how is trying to go through that as quickly as possible. But since I'd rather learn how to do stuff myself, I'm afraid this isn't too useful to me. Thank you very much for your input, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a pretty simple way to update an activity from within itself using a `Timer` and a `android.os.Handler`. The idea is to give the activity an interface (e.g. `IUpdateable`) that exposes an update method. Then extend the `TimerTask` to take `(Handler, IUpdateable)` as arguments and keep references to it. In the `TimerTask`'s `run()` method, call e.g. `updateableActivity.update()`. In the activity, instantiate a `Timer` and schedule `new UpdateTask(new Handler(), this);`.
This way you have an actually reusable approach (using an interface makes this easy to implement in any activity). If this was unclear, have a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/j-fliegenschmidt/6479668).

Answer (score 1):

Read about [Binding to a Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) from the official Android docs.

It should answer all of your questions.

Basically, the idea is that you "bind" to a service, and doing that gives you the service object. From there, you can just call the service's methods directly. In your case, you'd probably want a method declared in your service called notifyButton1Pressed() or something similar.

To refresh the Activity's views in an interval, use a TimerTask and a Timer. Those are pretty self-explanatory if you research them via Google.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I will definitely go and read through the basics. But as for the regular updates, a timer won't do since the tasks are runnables, and UI Updates are not allowed from any other than the UI thread

Comment: Inside your TimerTask, use a Handler to post the runnables to the UI thread.

Comment: Here is a complete example http://blog.philippheckel.com/2012/06/10/android-example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging/

Comment: Okay, Timer and Handler are indeed a magical combination, works like a charm. I haven't figured out the binding by now due to lack of time, but I'm certain that will work just as fine. Thanks for all the input, gonna accept this answer now.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update your `activity` from `service`, you have to `register` an `BroadcastReceiver` in your `activity`. In the `receiver` you do your update, and in the service, you have to `sendBroadcast` to your activity. And information between `activity` and `service` you could send through `Intent` which is sent by `sendBroadcast`.

Comment: Thank you for your input, though I feel that a timed update is surely womething to use a timer for. I have tried sending intents, but I think a binding is more useful. Not that I could actually judge it, but it feels like less overhead.